# Android ListViews: Update headerView of a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView as HeaderView of my ListView. I want to update HeaderView of my ListView when any element is added in the ListView of header. How can we do this?
Because I am updating the adapter of ListView in the header and notifyingDataSetChange as well as invalidating the view. Still it is not updated. Here is my piece of code:

```
    drawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    View HeaderView = getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.favourites, null);
    favouritesList = (ListView) HeaderView
            .findViewById(R.id.FavouritesList);
    favList = new ArrayList();
    favList.add("");
    FavAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,favList);
    favouritesList.setAdapter(FavAdapter);

    drawerList.addHeaderView(HeaderView); // Setting as header to ListView
```

In an function

```
FavAdapter.AddItem(associatedItem);
FavAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
favouritesList.invalidateViews();
drawerList.invalidateViews();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really put `ListView` as an another `ListView`'s header. Make your `Adapter` return two different types of Views.

To do that you'll need to manipulate with `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` methods within your adapter. Then inside of your Adapter's `getView()` just recognize which type is associated with a given `position` and create a `View` accordingly.